# How to convert the arc chart in to bar chart, build with SVG path and Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am new to SVG and I need to convert the arc chart to bar chart. following is a Javascript code and jsfiddle link of Arc chart.

```
function setArc(arc, percent) {

var angle = 75;
var radius = 50;

var path = "M200,200";

for(var i = 0; i <= percent; i++) {
    angle -=3.6;  
    angle %= 360;
    var radians= (angle/180) * Math.PI;

    var x = 100 + Math.cos(radians) * -1 * radius;
    var y = 100 + Math.sin(radians) * radius;

    if(i==0) {
        path += ' M ' + x + ' ' + y;
    }
    else {
        path += ' L ' + x + ' ' + y;
    }
}

arc.setAttribute('d', path);
```

}

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Us6Lw/)

Thanks

Comment: Can we do this with some editing in current Javascript code or need to write new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it should be enough to delete `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`. It will get you a straight diagonal line.

Then choose one from the following:

- for vertical bar change the calculation of `var x` to `var x = 0`
- for horizontal bar change the calculation of `var y` to `var y = 0`

Here is simplified your function for vertical bar: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6CJu/)